# Parallel Execution with pthread_cond_broadcast?

Tags: c++, multithreading, synchronization, posix

I would like to use pthread_cond_broadcast() to wake up all threads that is waiting for the same condition.

However, it seems like those threads can't really run in parallel because they have to share the same mutex.

Am I right?  Or there is a way to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not everything can be converted to run in parallel. In any program worth to mention there are always parts that must be run sequentially (say, sharing common resource). Thus, we usually talk about parts that can be run concurrently, and parts - that could not.If something "is waiting for the same condition" then, probably, this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Each thread must acquire the lock as it wakes up, but if there is work immediately following that can proceed in parallel, then simply release the lock at the earliest point at which it's safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping that there was some way to not share the same lock on the same condition variable.